# Decision Tree - What is more efficient a few nodes with hundreds of branches or hundreds of binary nodes (2 branches)?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

To make it simple, let's imagine a single category which can have 500 different values. For example city: nameCity1, nameCity2, ..., nameCity500.

What is more efficient, to have one single decision tree which will have 500 branches or to make some feature engineering and transform this category into 500 binary categories? So we will end up with 500 nodes with just two branches each.

I am planned to use this in xgboost, but I guess same will apply to decision trees or boosted decision trees.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to asking "what is better, ID3 or CART"?

Comment: @Digio I don't know about ID3 or CART. Can't tell you

Comment: "More efficient" in what sense? Computation cost? Prediction accuracy? Memory consumption? Vague question may attract vague answers.

Comment: Then you should study the differences between these two tree structures to get your answer. ID3 exhausts all levels in a single node, CART uses a binary tree structure. Since CART is the model of choice in both random forest and xgboost, this has already been somewhat answered.

Comment: Single trees have been demonstrated definitively not to be competitive in terms of predictive discrimination, and to be highly unstable unless the sample size is astronomical.

Comment: @JanKukacka In Prediction accuracy